# A Video as Background in an View

Tags: android, animation, view, background

Is there any way to Animate a Background on a normal View?

At our "startscreen" we would like to have a background that's actually a bit animated so we want to let a light fly around a Text. I could render this as Video or a set of pictures or what else. In front of it should be the normal Buttons as they are right now. At the moment it's a simple picture. Is there any way to do this?

Here is the current XML. Really straight forward

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/porta_aenigma_title_bm"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

    <helpers.ui.ChangedButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:onClick="startIntro"
        android:text="@string/button1" />

    <helpers.ui.ChangedButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="startSettingMenuButton"
        android:text="@string/button2" />

     <helpers.ui.ChangedButton
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="startLeadbord"
        android:text="@string/leadbord" />

     <helpers.ui.ChangedButton
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="startCreditsButton"
        android:text="@string/button3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm ot sure, but another way you could implement this is to use a RelativeLayout that holds the buttons on top of a full width/height video view, and set the background of hte buttons to transparent so the video shows through.

Comment: how to i dell the videoView to be in background of the buttons? to do your solution i just added the Viedoview above the buttons into the xml and filled parrents